# Why does pylint not want the parent class used in a super call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super, pylint

I have a piece of code that appeared to be working as intended. However I recently noticed pylint was flagging a line for E1003 which is "when an argument other than the current class is given as first argument of the super builtin."

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def something(cls):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def something(cls):
        print("B")

class C(B):
    @classmethod
    def execute(cls):
        super().something()                 # This calls B.something
        something = super(B, cls).something # Shorthanding a reference to A.something
        something()                         # This calls A.something
        super(B, cls).something()           # This calls A.something as well

c = C()
c.execute()
```

pylint only flags the last call to super(B,cls).something. It would rather me call super() or super(C, cls). But if my intention is to call A.something then this would be wrong.

Why wouldn't it flag both uses of super(B, cls)? Is this a false positive or is there a good reason I should not be trying to reach A.something from the grandchild class C?

This is for python 3.8.2 and pylint version 2.4.4

Comment: I'd say the unflagged case is a false negative. Passing a class other than the current class to `super` is almost always a brainfart or newbie error.

Comment: You happen to be doing it deliberately, but that's likely to do the wrong thing in the presence of multiple inheritance, and even with single inheritance, it pierces through the interface `B` presents to clients. If you specifically want to call `A.something()`, I'd just do it with literally `A.something()`. (If you want to call `A.something` with `C` as `cls`, I'd rethink the design - if subclasses of `B` need the `A` implementation, maybe `B` shouldn't override it.)

Comment: Fair enough, this was prompting me to look at the design again anyway. Thanks